How do you secure OpenTelemetry on the browser against false spans for anonymous users?
I saw that an OpenTelemetry instrumentation on the browser, but I was wondering how does one secure it?
Primarily the handling of false spans from anonymous users, I can't seem to find a way of preventing it because the spans are sent to a tracing endpoint and there's no reasonable way of securing that connection unless there's a separate user specific authentication.
For authorized users it's easy enough to rate limit.  But for anonymous I don't think it's possible.

This question has nothing to do with information security and thus is off-topic on Security SE.
